# Use Multiple DataTables in one DataSet to Insert new records in Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable, dataset, oledb

VB2010 I have one DataSet and I add multiple tables, I then fill in these tables, and then insert those records into an Access db.

```
    'create a new DataSet
    Dim dsNav As New DataSet

    'first table
    Dim daTrips As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Trips", connNav)
    daTrips.Fill(dsNav, "Trips")
    Dim cbTrips As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daTrips)

   'second table
    Dim daCars = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Cars", connNavDb)
    daCars.Fill(dsNav, "Cars")
    Dim cbCars As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daCars)

    'here i open a huge text file and depending on the data i encounter, I create
    'a new DataRow and add it to the appropriate table. i add many new rows to each
    'table. for example
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = {tblCars}.NewRow()
    dsNewRow.Item("CarId") = textline.Substring(0, 10)
    dsNewRow.Item("CarMake") = textline.Substring(11, 15)
    tblCars.Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

    'i finish reading the text file and filling up the tables in the one DataSet
    'now i want to insert those records into the Access db
    Dim rowCnt1 As Integer = daTrips.Update(dsNav, "Trips")
    Dim rowCnt2 As Integer = daCars.Update(dsNav, "Cars")
```

The first update works but on the second update I get the exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)

I've looked at various articles and they all suggest updating a database with one DataSet containing multiple DataTables is do-able, but just cant figure out why this is bombing.

Comment: Difficult to say what's happening. I will try to see what is the command text of the insert command on the daCars adapter. `daCars.InsertCommand.CommandText`

Comment: So I added a debug Debug.Print(daTrips.InsertCommand.CommandText) right before the daTrips.Update and it throwws an exception System.NullReferenceException. Same thing with UpdateCommand. I dont set those up at all. I thought the OleDbCommandBuilder set those up for you.

Comment: The Cars table contains only the two fields above or there are other fields? Could you show the names of these other fields if exists?

Comment: Also, try with this - `daCars.InsertCommand = cbCars.GetInsertCommand();` the look at then InsertCommand.CommandText

Comment: Again, the Cars table has a primary key defined? If you want commandbuilder to work with updates, the table has to have a
primary key.

Comment: No there are tons more fields and several more tables. i just showed these two for simplicity. Dont belive any of the fields are reserved words. The Cars table in the Database has an multi-field index and these same fields are set as primary keys. That's in the database table. In the code my DataTable seems to not have any primary keys. Do I have to set those manually to match the db table?

Comment: No, you could try with `daCars.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` just before the Fill method call [Refs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.missingschemaaction.aspx)

Comment: ok I added daCars.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey to my DataAdapter. Seems that the keys are now part of the DataTable but still getting the exception. Just cant seem to figure out whats going on.

Comment: Last thing, why do you use two different connections? (daTrips on connNav, daCars on connNavDb)

Comment: Im going to fix that since I can use only one DataAdapter. I changed it because i thought that may be the source of the problem.

Comment: OK I think I have found the major issue. First I would like to apologize for being so ignorant that I thought it couldn't possibly be my fields. I re-read the entire thread and your second post led me to double-check. Sure enough three tables had fields with spaces, slashes, and one reserved word 'Time'. I changed those in the db and in my code and it works. wow!!! agin apologies. I should have followed your lead initially.

Comment: So now on to the DataAdapter. How should I use one instance of the DataAdapter? I seem to be having trouble managing the one dataadapter and then creating the OleDbCommandBuilder for each table so that I can update it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it was nighttime here. Well, two DataAdapters are right. And each one should have its commandbuilder. You can't change the source schema in the DataAdapter because then the CommandBuilder will be out of synch with its adapter. So let's go with two Adapters each one with its CommandBuilder, but, if the database is the same, then you really need only one connection.

Comment: Gotcha. It works great as it is. How do I mark this thread as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish to put everything discovered in comments as an answer

1. Try to avoid fields using reserved keywords in your tables (also fields with spaces embedded)
2. CommandBuilders needs primary key infos, so add a `adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` to recover primary key informations from the db schema
3. Use the same connection for the Update as for the Fill

   ```
   Dim dsNav As New DataSet 
   'first table 
   Dim daTrips As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Trips", connNav) 
   daTrips.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey 
   daTrips.Fill(dsNav, "Trips") 
   Dim cbTrips As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daTrips) 

   'second table 
   Dim daCars = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Cars", connNav) 
   daCars.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey 
   daCars.Fill(dsNav, "Cars") 
   Dim cbCars As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daCars) 

   'here i open a huge text file and depending on the data i encounter, I create 
   'a new DataRow and add it to the appropriate table. i add many new rows to each 
   'table. for example 
   Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = {tblCars}.NewRow() 
   dsNewRow.Item("CarId") = textline.Substring(0, 10) 
   dsNewRow.Item("CarMake") = textline.Substring(11, 15) 
   tblCars.Rows.Add(dsNewRow) 

   'i finish reading the text file and filling up the tables in the one DataSet 
   'now i want to insert those records into the Access db 
   Dim rowCnt1 As Integer = daTrips.Update(dsNav, "Trips") 
   Dim rowCnt2 As Integer = daCars.Update(dsNav, "Cars")
   ```

Comment: I have also found that non-standard characters in fields throw off the update. You already mentioned spaces but several of my fields had a "/" and that was also problematic. again thanks.

Comment: For some(not all) characters you can get around this by surrounding the field name with square brackets: []. But then you need to explicitly set up the command text to accomodate for the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting up the `insertcommand` and the `updatecommand` properties of your `dataadapter`?

From your error it looks like the `dataadapter` is trying to insert the record into the database but the `insertcommand` isn't instantiated or given a value so its throwing the error.

Since data adapters decide what to do on the `.Update` call by examining each row in the datatables `rowstate` then any rows that you add to your table will try to use the `insertcommand` attached to your `dataadapter`.

Try setting up the `insertcommand` and `updatecommand` on your `dataadapters` and try running it again and see what happens from there.

Comment: I dont set insertcommand or updatecommand properties. I thought that was the purpose of the OleDbCommandBuilder.

Comment: I've never used the command builder personally I prefer to manually set up the commands so I Know what its doing. I'd be suprised if thats what the command builder did simply because how would it know the schema of your database? Either way, if you set the insert and update commands up and try it again it should work fine.